# Weird python error when using lxml and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm using python to write a crawler, since I need to parse html so I import lxml but it comes out an wierd error:

```
<type 'dict'>
{'xpath': '//ul[@id="i-detail"]/li[1]', 'name': u'\u6807\u9898'}

<type 'dict'>
{'xpath': '//ul[@id="i-detail"]/li[1]', 'name': u'\u6807\u9898'}

<type 'dict'>   
{'xpath': '//ul[@id="i-detail"]/li[1]', 'name': u'\u6807\u9898'}
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line     522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line     477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "fetcher.py", line 78, in run
    self.extractContent(html)
  File "fetcher.py", line 151, in extractContent
    m = tree.xpath(c['xpath'])
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'

<type 'dict'>
{'xpath': '//ul[@id="i-detail"]/li[1]', 'name': u'\u6807\u9898'}
```

Here's a piece of my code:

```
for c in self.contents:
  print type(c)
  print c
  m = tree.xpath(c['xpath'])
```

Please help me with these two questions:

1. Why the type is `dict` but the error says NoneType ?
2. I'm tring to match something in the "tree", but it doesn't work (The website is encoded under GBK, could the encoding type cause this kind of problems ?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are getting an `AttributeError`, which means that `tree` has no `xpath` attribute as it has become `None`, not that `c` has no `xpath` key, that'd be a `KeyError` instead.

   Clearly we are missing some code here, where `tree` is set to `None.
2. You are not printing the result of your `tree.xpath()` calls, so there is nothing in your code (as shared with us here) that prints `m`. The `tree.xpath()` calls could be working fine for all we know.

Reading between the lines and speculating a little, you are assigning the result of `tree.xpath()` back to `tree`, and your XPath expression didn't match anything and returned None. The next time into the loop, you now have `None` instead of an `ElementTreeNode`, so the `xpath()` call fails with an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, the error is telling you that `tree` is None, since that's what you're trying to read the `xpath` attribute of.  But you are printing the type of `c`, not `tree`.

I can't understand what you're asking with your second question.